# mern project won't deploy on render.com

Tags: javascript, mern, render.com

I have a mern project and I'm trying to deploy it. Everything seems to be working fine but I am getting this:

`Your service is live :tada: Aug 23 01:38:25 PM Server started Aug 23 01:38:27 PM Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat ‘/opt/render/project/src/server/client/build/index.html’ Aug 23 01:38:29 PM ==> Detected service running on port 7001 Aug 23 01:38:29 PM ==> Docs on specifying a port: Web Services | Render · Cloud Hosting for Developers`

I did yarn build and I have the build folder in my client folder and index.html file but when I click on the website I get "not found".
This my repo: https://github.com/rawanarafat/SpotifyWrapped2.git

I tried changing the root directory and the build and start command but it's not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the following line looks for static files inside the current directory:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));
```

You need to change it to:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'client', 'build')));
```

Same for `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build', 'index.html'));` - you need to change that as well.

Comment: how would this res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build', 'index.html')); look ? like this res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..' , 'client','build', 'index.html'));?

Comment: didn't work still getting "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/opt/render/project/src/server/client/build/index.html'
Aug 23 06:25:41 PM  ==> Detected service running on port 7001
Aug 23 06:25:41 PM  ==> Docs on specifying a port: https://render.com/docs/web-services#port-detection"